# Can JSON make a field appear conditionally in a view if it contains a value?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

Please can you help me with a problem I have, using JSON to customize a view?

I'm creating a glossary, using Lists. The List contains all the metadata for a term – then I'm using the list web part to show some of the fields in a SharePoint page.

If the term has an acronym, I want it to appear in brackets next to the term. So this is what I've got so far:

```
{
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-row-title"
            },
            "txtContent": "=[$Title] + '(' + [$field_1] + ')'"
          }
```

`field_1`  contains the acronym.

But I only want `field_1`, and the brackets surrounding it, to display if it contains a value.

E.g. at the moment, the code makes this happen:

```
Protected Designation of Origin (PDO)

Cheese (-)
```

– where "-" represents a null value in `field_1`.

So to the question... Do you know if there's any JSON syntax I can use, to make a field and some surrounding text appear conditionally, if the field contains a value?

I've looked at the code samples in the [list formatting samples library](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting) – and there seems to be a way to do it, using `=if`, but the samples are all for conditional formatting, like changing the color, rather than showing or hiding text.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using JSON expression like this:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "sp-row-title"
    },
    "txtContent": "=[$Title] + if([$field_1] == '' || [$field_1] == '-', '', '(' + [$field_1] + ')')"
}
```

**Documentation**: [JSON formatting syntax reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, that worked perfectly! And what a lightning response. Many thanks indeed.